# Knockout + jQuery datatables "enable" binding lost after clicking on pagination

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, datatables

I have hooked up several components: Knockout, jQuery DataTables + custom KnockOut DataTables, Bootstrap pagination etc. It's is based on this example: http://chadmullins.com/javascript/knockout-js-series-part-2-binding-knockout-js-to-a-datatables-grid/

Now, this all works perfectly - until I click on one of the controls of the pagination. It seems that somehow the "enable" binding breaks.

This is the binding:

```
<button data-bind="click: $parent.AddToCart, enable: !$parent.InBasket($data)">Add</button>
```

Forgive me for linking to a Fiddle, but regarding the dependencies I think this is the easiest way for demonstrating the "problem". Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/K8hhx/

Anybody seen this before?

Comment: Providing a Fiddle is the best thing you could do. Your fiddle ain't working though, something about jQuery

Comment: Strange, no problems here: http://i8.photobucket.com/albums/a50/snaack/fiddle.png

Comment: Open it up in chrome and check dev tools (F12) :)

Comment: ?? The screenshot I posted IS from Chrome, and my Dev Tools is not displaying any errors. What errors do you get? I am using CDN's for external libraries, perhaps you cannot connect to these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a subtle, but common problem in using knockout.

The problem is in the `$parent.InBasket($data)` function call as below.

```
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-mini btn-primary" type="button" 
               data-bind="click: $parent.AddToCart, 
               enable: !$parent.InBasket($data)">
                  Add</button>
    </td>
```

The problem is that the function is not is not an observable.  While it looks okay, it can causes problems like you are seeing.

I changed the html to be

```
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-mini btn-primary" type="button"
            data-bind="click: $parent.AddToCart, enable: !InBasket()">Add</button>
    </td>
```

And the item data model is -

```
var CartItem = function(name) {
    var self = this;
    self.Name = ko.observable(name);
    self.InBasket = ko.observable(false);  /// NEW
}
```

By putting the InBasket in the item datamodel, when it's status is updated, knockout knows how to update the screen as you page.  From a performance point of view, it is faster because every time the screen is redrawn, you no longer have to search the cart to see is in it.

Updated at http://jsfiddle.net/photo_tom/K8hhx/4/.  Actual code changes are fairly small.

BTW: I'm thinking of using this Datatables/Knockout in an upcoming project have having a real sample to look at will be useful.

Comment: I've accepted your answer because it makes perfect sense. See http://jsfiddle.net/J4Hye/1/ However, this slightly differs from my actual situation and I have different problems now. :(